# unable to load html page into a frame tag

Tags: html

I'm trying to segment the total window into 2 frames.In those two frames I'm trying to load the html page.I'm able to segement an entire window into frames but unable to load a html page within that frame.

My test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Target Frames</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="200, *">
   <frame src="/home/divya/html_docs/current/menu.html" name="menu_page" />
   <frame src="/home/divya/html_docs/current/main.html" name="main_page" />
   <noframes>
   <body>
      Your browser does not support frames.
   </body>
   </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Can anyone suggest me about this issue ...

Comment: frame is deprcated. use iframe instead.

Comment: you should put in the src attribute relative paths

Comment: I've tried using iframe also.But unable to load a page

Comment: yea try relative path. `<frame src="menu.html" name="menu_page" />` I am assuming your htmls are in same dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting absolute server paths of the files.
In your case you will get then:

```
http://yourdomain.com/home/divya/html_docs/current/menu.html
```

put there urls relative to your test.html file. like: `src="current/menu.html"`
or if the files are in the same directory just `src="menu.html"`

Comment: btw, you should really use iframes, The <frameset> tag is not supported in HTML5. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp